# Evaluation conundrum: functions that call NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, fitting

Consider the following function of one variable, `k`:

```
ClearAll[bar];
bar[k_] := NIntegrate[k t, {t, 0, 3}];
```

My actual integrand is more complicated than just `k t`, of course. This one could be integrated analytically, but my real `bar` cannot (to my knowledge). I'll show it below, but this integrand is a Minimal Viable Example (MVE).

All is well should I try to evaluate `bar` over a few values of `k`:

```
In[150]:= Table[bar[k], {k, 1, 4, 0.5}]
```

> ```
> Out[150]= {4.5, 6.75, 9., 11.25, 13.5, 15.75, 18.}
> ```

But plotting it runs into trouble:

```
Plot[bar[k], {k, 1, 4}]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand k t has evaluated to non-numerical 
> values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,3}}.
> ```

That eventually produces a plot, but what I really need to do, `NMinimize`, does not work at all:

```
NMinimize[{bar[k], k >= 1, k <= 4, k \[Element] Reals}, k, 
  EvaluationMonitor -> Print[bar[k]]]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand k t has evaluated to non-numerical 
> values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,3}}.
>
> NIntegrate[k t,{t,0,3}]
> ```

I'd appreciate any advice.

PS: my real integrand is

```
(tt[r, t] - qs2[k t])^2
```

where

```
tt[r, t]
```

is

```
Piecewise[{{1, t > r}, {(r + t)/(2*r), -r <= t <= r}}, 0]
```

and

```
qs2[k t]
```

is

```
Piecewise[{{0, 0.5 + k*t <= 0}, {E^(-(0.5 + k*t)^(-2)), 
    0.5 + k*t > 0}}, 0]/
 (Piecewise[{{0, 0.5 - k*t <= 0}, {E^(-(0.5 - k*t)^(-2)), 
     0.5 - k*t > 0}}, 0] + Piecewise[{{0, 0.5 + k*t <= 0}, 
    {E^(-(0.5 + k*t)^(-2)), 0.5 + k*t > 0}}, 0])
```

My real problem is to find the values of `k` that minimize the integral of this integrand from `t=0` to `t=3 r` as a function of `r` between `r=0.07` and `r=8`.  It's a least-squares fit of `qs2[k t]` (non-linear mollifier) to `tt[r, t]` (clipped linear function).

Comment: This is a standard issue. Use `bar[k_?NumericQ]` and things will work.

Comment: Leonid, if you elevate that to an answer, I'll mark it. I'm unblocked; thanks :)

Comment: I'd rather close this as a dupe, if you don't mind, because this has been discussed in very similar settings many times already.

Comment: Don't mind at all.  I'll be grateful to see the other answers!

Comment: The relevant "hub" answer is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037). I will vote to close as a dupe of that question.